# No exact matches in call to initializer when using initializer syntax with dictionaries

Tags: swift, dictionary

Creating an array using either literal syntax or initializer syntax works.

```swift
var arr1: Array<Int> = [3, 4, 5]
var arr2 = Array<Int>([3, 4, 5])
```

However, when using the initializer syntax with a dictionary returns an error.

```swift
var dict1: Dictionary<Int, String> = [1: "aaa", 2: "bbb"]
var dict2 = Dictionary<Int, String>([1: "aaa", 2: "bbb"]) // error
var dict3 = [Int: String]([1: "aaa", 2: "bbb"]) // error
```

Not including the value in the initializer syntax and then assigning it to the dictionary after solves the issue.

```swift
var dict4 = Dictionary<Int, String>()
dict4 = [1: "aaa", 2: "bbb"]
```

My question is does using the initializer syntax with a value for a dictionary return an error?

---

*Xcode Version 14.0.1*

Comment: It's because `Array<Int>([3, 4, 5])` is short for `Array<Int>.init([3, 4, 5])`, and there is a `init(_ sequence:)` on `Array`. But no "equivalent" in Dictionary.

Comment: There *is* a `Sequence` initializer for `Dictionary`.  It's just that it takes a `Sequence` whose elements are tuples, `(Key, Value)`, which in this example is `(Int, String)`, and unfortunately `Dictionary` literal doesn't qualify, because it's a two-step conversion, so the compiler doesn't find an exact match.  You have to help it out.

Comment: It does seem like the kind of thing that compiler *could* do, and I'm not immediately sure why it doesn't, but there may be a good reason it doesn't.   It may be a good question to ask on `Swift.org` where people who work on the compiler might see it and give you a more definite answer.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries have to know how to deal with non-unique values.

The closest initializer to what you're looking for is:

```
Dictionary<Int, String>(uniqueKeysWithValues: [1: "aaa", 2: "bbb"])
```

That will give its own new error:

> error: initializer 'init(uniqueKeysWithValues:)' requires the types '(key: Int, value: String)' and '(Int, String)' be equivalent

So you'd need to do a `map` to remove the the `key:` and `value:` tuple labels:

```
Dictionary<Int, String>(uniqueKeysWithValues: [1: "aaa", 2: "bbb"].map { ($0.key, $0.value) })
```

Which is pretty clunky. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am currently learning Swift, I was wondering why this syntax works for arrays and sets but not for dictionaries the way I thought it would be.

Comment: @MichaelKnightly There is `Sequence` intializer for `Dictionary`, but it's `init<S>(_ elements: S) where S: Sequence, Element == (Key, Value)`, so you'd need to pass an array of tuples, `(Int, String)`.  `.map` translates the dictionary literal into an `Array` of the element correct type, and of course `Array` is a `Sequence`.  You could extend `Dictionary` to have an `init` that accepts another `Dictionary`, if you really want that syntax, but it's simpler to just use the assignment syntax of your `dict1` example.

Comment: @MichaelKnightly Don't think of it in terms of syntax. These built in types have initializers like any others. It's a matter of what the standard library API offers